# Angular script gets executed (fired) after page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);

            myAppModule.factory('studentFactory', function (){
                // The whole factory goes here.
            });

            myAppModule.controller('studentsController', ['$scope', 'studentFactory', function ($scope, studentFactory){
                $scope.students = [];
                studentFactory.getStudents(function (data){
                    $scope.students = data;
                });
                studentFactory.removeStudent(function (data){
                    alert('test');
                    $scope.students = data;
                });
            }])
       </script>
</head>
<body ng-app='myApp'>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

The `alert('test')` gets fired when page loads. How can I fix it? Please nevermind the issues in code, I am just working on it.

Here's the code in Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/u7c13AIdKPjmdkzRUPXd?p=preview

Comment: Can we see the implementations of .removeStudents? And .getStudents? It's likely they're not async.

Comment: Sure, best would be to go to the link in Plunker I have provided later in the edit.

Comment: Also, it is yet to be implemented.

Comment: When do you want removeStudent fired? Do you want it fired when a click event happens? Do you want it fired after some time has lapsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're calling the functions removeStudents in the controller on instantiation. If you want it to wait for some event before firing, you need to bind it to the event. For instance, you'd wrap it in some click function like so:

```
$scope.whenIClickMyButton = function () {
    studentFactory.removeStudent(function (data){
        alert('test');
        $scope.students = data;
    });
}

<button ng-click="whenIClickMyButton()">Click Me</button>
```

And the add that as the click event. For now, it fires every time you instantiate the controller because you're calling it every time.